# Blob Triggered Azure Function not starting in Virtual Studio

Tags: python, azure, function

I am trying to start a new Azure Function in Virtual Studio,  I have the Azure functions extension installed along with the Azure Account and Azure Resources.

I have followed the local steps to create a new Blob triggered function via the Workspace, and this all goes fine.  However, when I go to start the function by pressing F5, I get the following errors and I am unable to fix it.

```
Found Python version 3.9.12 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4629 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.6.1.18388

[2022-07-12T14:34:35.612Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '099ebc77-8104-49e1-882f-10970f460f13'.
[2022-07-12T14:34:35.612Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
```

I need to do this within Virtual Studio so I can install 3rd party dependencies for my needs.

Can anyone help, I am quite new to developing Azure Functions.

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified. Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

I have overcome this type of error by reinstalling the **Azure Function Core Tools**.

Try to remove the NuGet cache to avoid ***could not load file or assembly error***.

```
# List all the local cache
 dotnet nuget locals all -list
# Clear cache
 dotnet nuget locals all --clear
```

[image]

After cleared the cache rebuild and run the Azure Function.